# Angularjs test with Jest module injection

Tags: angularjs, testing, jestjs

Trying to test angular services with Jest and got this error:

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'superag' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

How do I mock my module 'superag' and make available to `mathService`?

Do I have to import the `app.js` file with the module declaration every test I make?

Ps.: I've tried with `beforeEach(module('superag'))` too without success

**package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js}",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.9",
    "jest-cli": "^23.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.9"
  }
}
```

**math.service.js**

```
function MathService(){

    var addTwoNumbers = function(x, y){
      return x + y;
    };

    return {
      addTwoNumbers
    };
  }
angular.module('superag').factory('mathservice', MathService);
```

**math.service.test.js**

```
require('angular');
require('angular-mocks');
require('./math.service.js');

describe('Math service - addTwoNumbers', () => {

  beforeEach(
    angular.mock.module('superag')
  );

  var _mathservice;

  beforeEach(inject((mathservice) => {
    _mathservice = mathservice;
  }));

  it('1 + 1 should equal 2', () => {
    var actual = _mathservice.addTwoNumbers(1,1);
    expect(actual).toEqual(2);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when you declare a dependency on a module that isn't defined anywhere or hasn't been loaded in the current browser context.

When you receive this error, check that the name of the module in question is correct and that the file in which this module is defined has been loaded (either via `<script>` tag, loader like require.js, or testing harness like karma).

A less common reason for this error is trying to "re-open" a module that has not yet been defined.

To define a new module, call `angular.module` with a name and an array of dependent modules, like so:

```
// When defining a module with no module dependencies,
// the array of dependencies should be defined and empty.
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

To retrieve a reference to the same module for further configuration, call angular.module without the array argument.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
```

Calling `angular.module` without the array of dependencies when the module has not yet been defined causes this error to be thrown. To fix it, define your module with a name and an empty array, as in the first example above.

Comment: Inside my test or into my service?

Comment: Already tried to define into `BeforeEach` without success... :(

Comment: Tried with `beforeEach(module('superag'))` and `beforeEach(angular.module('superag', []))`

Comment: if you want to mock a module maybe you can try this

 `beforeEach(function(){`

    `module('moduleToMock');`

    `module(function ($provide) {`

        `$provide.value('yourService', serviceMock);`

    `});`

`});`

Comment: without success ... [I've created a repo](https://github.com/rodgerpaulo/jest-with-angularjs) with my tries, could you have a look? I appreciate your effort so far

Comment: Yeah, ill see your repo, anyway i feel curious with this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the module under test using the module function provided in angular-mocks, so it is available in your tests, per [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).

```
beforeEach(module('superag'))
```

Then you can inject in your service.

Comment: Where is the superag module defined... can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: That's the case. I need to define `superag` inside the test, not require another file.

Comment: Thanks for your time